# Проблемы с адаптивной версткой

Tags: html, css, responsive

Всем доброго времени суток. При верстке своей портфолио страницы столкнулся с проблемой. Суть такая: мы имеем страницу с `max-width: 100%;` и имеем на ней `header` с таким же `max-width`. Затем мы добавляем поверх этого `header'а` картинку. `Margin'ом` задаем определенную позицию для этой картинки. Получаем такую картину: [image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Самое интересное наступает тогда, когда мы начинаем менять ширину страницы, получается вот такая белиберда: [image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Такое происходит после того, как край окна доходит до картинки. Помогите с решением проблемы, пожалуйста.

```html
    <div id="header">
    <img src="img/profile-ph.png" alt="Profile pho">
    </div>
```

```css
#header{
    background: url(../img/header-bg.png) rgb(240,73,73);
    height: 3.75em;
}
#header img{
    margin-top: 5px;
    margin-left: 300px;
}
```

Comment: Если край окна доходит до картинки, то почему скриншот с белибердой такой широкий?

Comment: Для наглядности увеличил отступ картинки от края.

Comment: Как была задана "определенная позиция" картинки?

Comment: Какую роль у вас играет max-width: 100%? Зачем его используете и упоминаете его здесь

Comment: В html вставил картинку. Потом в css для этой картинки сделал margin-top: 5px; для расположения картинки по центру header'а, а потом margin-left: 45px; для перемещения картинки в сторону.

Comment: Для корректного отображения текста на странице, для предотвращения появления горизонтального скрола при изменении ширины окна.

Comment: Итак понятно, что картинку вы в html вставляете, а не в одно место. Горизонтальный скролл не должен появляться без всяких max-width. И, возможно, что-то вы нахимичи с размерами может заголовка, может всей страницы. Без кода страницы не понять, что вы там сделали.

Comment: Ситуация с проблемой появляется не когда появляется горизонтальный скролл и вы его двигаете вправо, чтобы посмотреть на картинку?

Comment: Нет, на странице вообще нет горизонтального скрола. Я просто уменьшаю ширину окна браузера и в тот момент, когда край браузера достигает картинки получается то, что получается.

Comment: не margin-top и ни для картинки а сделайте padding:5px: для header - margin`он  вы только блок header оттолкнёте

Comment: Все лучше сопровождать примерами кода, выкладывая его на [jsfiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/) или [codepen](http://codepen.io/)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

У вас у картинки стоит margin-left: 300px; когда размер экрана становится меньше, картинка остается на этой величине, а размер хедера уменьшается. 
Если вы используете margin и рассчитываете на адаптивную верстку, то лучше выставлять относительную величину в margin в % или vw, тогда ваша картинка будет кататься по хедеру без вылетов.
300px - это фиксированная  величина, соответственно либо меняйте условие в margin, либо создавайте медиа-запрос @media для расширения ниже и там выставляйте версию с другими параметрами margin. А для плавности перехода можно использовать в этом случае transition.

Answer (score 0):

Может так? У вас не очень понятный код: я внёс его в редактор и никакой проблемы не увидел

```css
#header{
  position: relative;
  background: url(../img/header-bg.png) rgb(240,73,73);
  height: 3.75em;
  padding: 5px 0;
}
#header img {
  display: block;
  position: absolute;
  width: 60px;
  height: 60px;
  left: 300px;
}
```

```html
<div id="header">
  <img src="https://i.stack.imgur.com/WZsJn.jpg?s=48&g=1" alt="Profile pho">
</div>
```